# Bind table entries into Spinner in SQLite Database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have created a table named Blood Group into my SQLiteDatabase. I have retrieved all data from table into logcat
But I am not able to bind the data into the Spinner.

```
ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, yourListFromDB);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    yourSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

Comment: Do you still get anything if you comment this line     spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
?

Comment: I changed my coding a bit.. insteading of binding the code directly from the database, I binded my whole data into STRING ARRAY first and then passed the array as the last parameter in spinnerAdapter

And it worked.

Thanks for the effort. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the alternative answer:

```
 ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, yourListFromDB);
    String bloodgroups[]={ "O +ve", "A+ve","B+ve","AB+ve"};
          spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,bloodgroups);
            yourSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```